# How to solve if bootstrap dropdown not working in app.php environment using symfony framework?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am working on a project using symfony 2.5.10 . I am also using sb admin bootstrap template.My problem is when I run my project it in my dev environment everything works perfectly but when I tried it in production environment, dropdown is not working.Everytime I click it jsut add `#` in the path. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you dumped the assets and then cleared your cache?

Comment: oh,, yes , I forgot that,,, thanks ,, I got it already I just dump my asset,,, :)